# reducing validation loss in CNN Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import pickle
import numpy as np
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.models import load_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Opening the files about data
X = pickle.load(open("X.pickle", "rb"))
y = pickle.load(open("y.pickle", "rb"))

# normalizing data (a pixel goes from 0 to 255)
X = X/255.0

# Building the model
model = Sequential()
# 3 convolutional layers
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))


model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.9))

# 5 hidden layers
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

# The output layer with 7 neurons, for 7 classes
model.add(Dense(13))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

# Compiling the model using some basic parameters
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
                optimizer="adam",
                metrics=["accuracy"])

# Training the model, with 40 iterations
# validation_split corresponds to the percentage of images used for the validation phase compared to all the images

print("X = " + str(len(X)))
print("y = " + str(len(y)))

history = model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=1000, validation_split=0.1)

# Saving the model
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file :
    json_file.write(model_json)

model.save_weights("model.h5")

print("Saved model to disk")

model.save('CNN.model')

# Printing a graph showing the accuracy changes during the training phase
print(history.history.keys())

plt.show()

plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])

plt.title('model accuracy')

plt.ylabel('accuracy')

plt.xlabel('epoch')

plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

The problem is that, I am getting lower training loss but very high validation accuracy. And accuracy of validation is also extremely low. How can I solve this issue? I have tried to increase the drop value up-to 0.9 but still the loss is much higher. I also tried using linear function for activation, but no use.

Please help.

[image: Loss of model looks like this]

Comment: This problem is too broad and unclear to give you a specific and good suggestion.  We would need informatione about your dataset for example. 

What is the learning curve like? Can you share a plot of training and validation loss during training?

Comment: I agree with what @FelixKleineBösing said, and I'll add that this might even be off topic.

Comment: @FelixKleineBösing I am using a custom data-set of various crop images, 50 images ini each folder. There are total 7 categories of crops I am focusing.

Comment: @ChinmayShendye We need a plot for the loss also, not only accuracy. In some situations, especially in multi-class classification, the loss may be decreasing while accuracy also decreases.

Comment: @ChinmayShendye So you have 50 images for each class? 350 images in total? I think that this is way to less data to get an generalized model that is able to classify your validation/test set with a good accuracy.

Comment: @FelixKleineBösing sorry for the late reply. I am editing the question with proper graph of both model accuracy and loss

Comment: @ChinmayShendye No problem. I edited my answer, see below.

Comment: @FelixKleineBösing I used augmentation  and now I am with 1500 images and more in each category. But the problem remains the same. I also reduced network complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is already mentioned, it is pretty hard to give a good advice without seeing the data.

What I would try is the following: 
- remove the Dropout after the maxpooling layer
- remove some dense layer
- add dropout between dense

If it´s then still overfitting, add dropout between dense layers

Edit: 
After I have seen the loss and accuracy plot I would suggest the following:

1. the highest priority is, to get more data.
2. then use data augmentation to even increase your dataset
3. further reduce the complexity of your neural network if additional data doesn’t help (but I think that training will slow down with more data and validation loss will also decrease for a longer period of epochs)

Comment: getting more data helped me in this case!!

Comment: @ChinmayShendye Nice :)

Comment: @ChinmayShendye If you have any similar questions in the future, ask them here: https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: May I please request you to guide me in implementing weight decay for the above model?

Comment: @JapeshMethuku Of course. Create a new Issue and I´ll help you.

Comment: Thank you so much. Here is the link https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/77604/weight-decay-in-resnet50
I am implementing finetuning based transfer learning approach where I'm unfreezing the layers 165 to 174. Please let me know if you want further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

**Data Augmentation** is the best technique to reduce overfitting. Try data generators for training and validation sets to reduce the loss and increase accuracy.

To learn more about Augmentation, and the available transforms, check out https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing

```
# Add our data-augmentation parameters to ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255.,
                               rotation_range = 40,
                               width_shift_range = 0.2,
                               height_shift_range = 0.2,
                               shear_range = 0.2,
                               zoom_range = 0.2,
                               horizontal_flip = True)

# Note that the validation data should not be augmented!
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255.)

# Flow training images in batches of 20 using train_datagen generator
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                batch_size = 20,
                                                class_mode = 'binary', 
                                                target_size = (150, 150))     

# Flow validation images in batches of 20 using test_datagen generator
validation_generator =  test_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_dir,
                                                      batch_size  = 20,
                                                      class_mode  = 'binary', 
                                                      target_size = (150, 150)) 

# Now fit the training, validation generators to the CNN model
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
        validation_data = validation_generator,
        steps_per_epoch = 100,
        epochs = 3,
        validation_steps = 50,
        verbose = 2,callbacks=[callbacks])
```